# Counting all rows with a limit

Tags: php, mysql

I need to filter (using where clauses) the rows in my table, count the total number of rows from this filter and then limit number of rows for pagination.

What is quickest/more efficient?

1. Count the rows with sql query. Select the rows with a limit with sql query.
2. Select all rows with sql query. Count the array with PHP. Split the array with PHP.

Or is there another way to count all rows and get a limited set of the results out?

Comment: 1 yes so you know how many pages you have, 2 select within limits -> http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm to display on page x

Comment: You want this function: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows   with it, no need to run your queries twice.

Comment: I know you are not asking about frameworks, but you should consider using one, such as Laravel (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset). Operations like this would be a lot easier to be done.

Comment: I am using Laravel, unfortunately eloquent is not good for complex queries so having to use raw.

Comment: @PedroMoreira This is really a database question, not a framework question. The answer would be the same regardless of framework, for example I use the code in my example in the F3 framework, WordPress, Java, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and the [`FOUND_ROWS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function to return the total number of rows even when a LIMIT is applied to the returned results. After you run your query the results will be returned, and then you can run `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to return the total number of rows without having to run the query again.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM my_table WHERE column = 'something' LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total_results;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries, one to retrieve total number of rows, another to get the rows. The first argument in `LIMIT` clause specifies the offset of the first row ( `current_page * post_per_page` ), and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return ( `post_per_page` ).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM table;

SELECT * FROM table LIMIT start, length;
```

Answer (score -1):

The MySQL `LIMIT` should do the trick for you. This is a more efficient approach, as it helps in fetching only the relevant records to be displayed and nothing else.

Note that the `startingIndex`, `numberOfRecordsPerPage` variables should be set before executing the query.

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE where 
(...) //ALL CONDITIONS go here
LIMIT startingIndex, numberOfRecordsPerPage;
```

From the [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15

In order to identify whether or not to expect any records in return, one must first run the query (with `COUNT` and without any `LIMIT` condition):

```
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE where (...) //ALL CONDITIONS go here`
```

and store it separately. This shall be the total records applicable to the `WHERE` clauses given.

If the sum `startingIndex`+`numberOfRecordsPerPage` is `>= TOTAL_COUNT` then that paginated set shall be the last of the whole list and the user should not be allowed to click the `NEXT` button.

PS: Also, as pointed out in the comments, you might want to look at a framework alternative, like `Criteria` API for `Java`, to the heavy weightlifting, particularly if your `WHERE` conditions are also generated dynamically.

Comment: I don't think this answers the original intent of the question which is "how do you know the total number of rows but only return X rows?". The issue is how do you know that `LIMIT 5,10` is going to return 6-15 if there are only 12 rows total (it can't)?